# How to make a G-WAN servlet close its connection silently without sending any reply

Tags: ddos, g-wan

How to have gwan send no reply to some requests, i.e. make a servlet closed silently without building and sending a reply?

It is useful to reduce the out-going bandwidth from the server side.

For collecting data only, there's no need to respond anything to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also close the connection from the servlet by doing something like (untested):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

char buf[1024];
int s = (int)get_env(argv, CLIENT_SOCKET);
shutdown(s, SHUT_WR);
while(read(s, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0);
close(s);
return 500;
```

Then return something like 500 like above so you don't have to build a reply.

Comment: Or, shall i **propose** to have a gwan built-in feature, i.e. whenever a servlet return 500 or 444 or 0, something like that, gwan will close the connection silently without building and sending a reply to the client?  Is it hard to add an **if-else** checking on this return value in gwan core?

Comment: Not bad at all: return 0; would do it and it is coherent with the handler behavior. Good point!

Comment: thnks a lot. Waiting for the implementation.

Comment: K. K. Lou, you should 'accept' the answers to your questions by clicking on its votes number to add a green tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a gwan `connection handler`.

I think this is the event that you need to catch on the handler. Since you want the servlet to run then close the connection after.

```
HDL_BEFORE_WRITE, // after a reply was built, but before it is sent
```

Here is a sample code for the `connection handler`. You still need to add your filter. This code will close all requests after the reply was built.

```
int init(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
   u32 *states = (u32*)get_env(argv, US_HANDLER_STATES);
   *states =  (1 << HDL_BEFORE_WRITE)
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long state = (long)argv[0];
    if(state == HDL_BEFORE_WRITE)
    {
        return 0; // Close connection
    }
    return(255); // continue G-WAN's default execution path
}
```

Comment: sorry, i don't know where to use the **init()** function. Will it be used by gwan internally, or shall it be placed somewhere in the main()?

Comment: You don't need to call it. G-WAN only runs the init() function once when it loads. main() function on the handler will get called on every request when you specify a state to catch. G-WAN's documentation and samples will give you more idea on what handlers are for.